# The value of Store_accessor is not modified from the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my model I have results

```
store_accessor :results
```

and in controller its like

```
        if current_user.test
          @results = current_user.test.results
        end
```

And I am printing this value at the front end it keeps showing `0`

```
    def update
      stats = user.test
      stats.data_will_change!
      attributes = { results: "#{(stats.results.to_i) + 1}" }
      stats.update_attributes(attributes)
    end
```

It's going through the function  but the value at the front-end is still `0`

Answer (score 1):

[`store_accessor`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods.html#method-i-store_accessor) requires at least two attributes

```rb
store_accessor :column_name, :attribute
```

`:column_name` column is presumed to be `Hash` like type eg `Hstore` in PostgreSQL or `json` or something like that.

`:attribute` than behaves like standard database column in ActiveRecord model.

You can then call something like:

```rb
model.attribute = 5
model.save
```

It also works with mass assignment

```rb
model.update(attribute: 5)
```

In your case it could look something like this:

```rb
store_accessor :results, :stats
```

```rb
    def update
      stats = user.test
      stats.update_attributes(stats: stats.results.to_i + 1)
    end
```